# Site on React/Vite doens't work in Safari. (Browser shows empty page)

Tags: reactjs, safari, vite

I use BrowserStack for testing my site on react 18/vite and when I test it in Safari 5.1 I can see only empty page. There are no any errors in console. (But site works correctrly in mobile safari)
[image]

I don't use any polyfills because vite adds polyfills under the hood.

I tried to find information about this situation and didn't find anything.

I tested in dev and prod modes.

Is it possible that site works on mobile Safari but doesn't work on desktop safari? Or there is problem in BrowserStack?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could confirm whether --force-local is in use with your BrowserStack Local Connection? For ref.: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/local-testing/binary-params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could confirm whether `--force-local` is in use with your BrowserStack Local Connection? For ref.: browserstack.com/docs/local-testing/binary-params

With `--force-local` flag, all the network requests on the remote test device will resolve via your local network, and hence the localhost:8000 will be reachable on BrowserStack's remote test device.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Vite only works for Safari >= 14

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html